# <td style='text-align: right'> incorrectly aligned in IE11

Tags: html-table, internet-explorer-11, text-alignment

I am trying to right align the values, but those are not aligning properly to the end of the column.

Example code:

```
<table id="demoTable1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:right; width:23%"><bean:message key="label.amount"/></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <c:forEach items="${demoForm.amount}" var="amt" >
        <tr>
            <td dntitle="myAmt" style="text-align:right; width:23%"> 
                <util:myCurrency name="amt" property="amtList" currProperty="curCode"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the Output looks like this:
[image: Table with mis-aligned column]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked any css properties associated with `td` tag?

Comment: no. I have not given any css properties.

Comment: Show a sample of HTML (not code that generates HTML) and CSS that actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: Have you checked the layout in the developer console?

Comment: @VPK i will check and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. Please refer the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/stutiawasthi27/gsu5frdk/

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `text-align`ment (it's `right` aligned, as you specified). It possibly has to do with `padding` or `margin` on the `<td>` or one of its children. We have no visibility over the actual markup (HTML) produced by `<util>` or any of the CSS applied to it. Without a [mcve] your question is (technically) unanswerable, therefore off-topic.